# QGIS field calculator: Subtracting values from specific fields

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, mapping, field-mapping

I am trying to create an Isopach map of two subsurface formations. If a well has the two formations in question, then I would like a new layer with the data created so I can contour the points.

I cant figure out how to create the expression needed in the field calculator.

I have two fields, Form Alias and Top Subsurface. I need to specify what two Form Alias's subsurface values I want subtracted and create a layer with this new information. I would think it would look like this: ('CHAT''Top Subsea') - ('LNSG''Top Subsea') = CHAT_to_LNSG_ISO[image]

Comment: So, for a given well (presumably identified with `Well_ID_1`) you expect to find exactly one record where `"Form Alias" = 'CHAT'` and one record where `"Form Alias" = 'LNSG'` - and if both exist, you want to subtract the `"Top Subsea"` value of one record from that of another?

Comment: Yes, your are exactly correct.